# Sharing data between an Angular Component and Service using Objects

Tags: angular

For my use case, I have a lot of simple features. These features usually consist of one Component to control the view and one or two Services (getting data, showing a grid etc). The data in component is fetched from APIs and I want to reflect the changes and share it with the Services.

The simplest way I can think of doing it is to declare a shared object on the Component/Services. Take a look at the following snippet to have a better idea

```
// In Component
class Comp {
  shared: {data1: number, data2: [] , .... };
  constructor(private serv: Serv) {
    this.serv.shared = this.shared;
  }
  onUpdateData1 () {
    this.shared.data1 = Math.random();
  }
}
```

```
// In Service
class Serv {
  shared: {data1: number, data2: [] , .... };

  workOnData1 () {
    console.log(this.shared.data1);
  }
}
```

The Components/Services are used with each other and not shared with other Components/Services. So, this approach gives me a very easy solution for sharing data between components and services.

Again what I am trying to achieve is to share data (preferably by reference) between a Component and Service (not between a Component and another Component). I would really appreciate a solution where I can change a variable in one and instantly make it available in other.

I am interested in what other approaches can I take to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: If the data from one component isn't going to be used in another component what really is the use of declaring variables in service here? You could declare the variables directly in the components and have the same functionality.

Comment: The data is going to be shared among the services. For example, a service will fetch the data. Another service will display the data in grid. The grid will require some extra data which it will use to show dynamic editing options. I may also have a charts service which will plot the data. All of these services will use the same data to to these tasks. Declaring the variable in a service makes the latest value available in that variable automatically whenever it gets updated in the component. The reason of using object is to preserve the reference in a shared variable.

Comment: Sharing an object using reference isn't good practice. It'll be difficult to maintain the application down the line. And displaying the data isn't the purpose of a service. It should be taken care by a controller. You need to look into RxJS observables to share data b/n services and components.

Answer (score 0):

sharing data by reference is generally a bad practice that leads to hard to maintain and understand code with a lot of hard to spot bugs.  The recommended approach, in angular, is using RxJS Observables.

```
class Serv {
  // subject as your source, private, expose public observable
  private _shared = new BehaviorSubject({data1: number, data2: [] , .... });
  shared$ = this._shared.asObservable();

  setData(newData) {
    // send new values with next
    this._shared.next(newData);
  }
}
```

then you use this in components by subscribing...

```
class Comp1 {
  shared: {data1: number, data2: [] , .... };
  constructor(private serv: Serv) {
    // set it
    this.serv.setData(this.shared);
  }
}

class Comp2 {
  shared: {data1: number, data2: [] , .... };
  constructor(private serv: Serv) {
    // get it
    this.serv.shared$.subscribe(s => this.shared = s)
  }
}
```